# How to report the scraping progress of X-Ray?

Tags: javascript, x-ray

Like I scrape 3 pages with the code below:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  .limit(3)
  .write('results.json')
```

How can I report the progression?

I tried the .then() but seems not work.

```
x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  .limit(3)
  .write('results.json')
  .then(
  //something to report the progression
  )
```

Or callback function which also wouldn't work

```
x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])(()=>{
  //something to report the progress
  })
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  .limit(3)
  .write('results.json')
```

Comment: You say the ".then" doesn't seem to work - how did you test it? Add in a console.log into it and see what happens such as .then((res) => { console.log(res) }) etc

Comment: I got his error:    TypeError: x(...).limit(...).paginate(...).write(...).then is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .then() can work, but not after write

.then() expected (I THINK!) a promise. after .write() there is nothing left.

You can try deleting the .write and using then to console.log the results like this:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  .limit(3)
/*   .write('results.json') */
  .then(result => {
  })
```

and that will print the title and link of the page you scraped.

you could use .then() and inside, print every result to a file using something like fs, for example

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
const fs = require('fs')
var x = Xray();



x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  .limit(3)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results)

    let res = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2);

    fs.writeFile('results.json', res, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err

      console.log('result saved!')
    })
  })
```

here JSON.stringify(results, null, 2) is just taking an object (results is an array of objects) and turning it into json (the third argument - that 2 - is just to make it pretty)

then using fs.writeFile (a native node module) you write the json object on results.json

you could even make it object by object using forEach()

like

```
 results.forEach(result => {
 //log the individual result and put in on an empty array, and then write the array
})
```